# Google Sheet: Array formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I made this formula: =`{filter(Sheet1!B1:AA22;Sheet1!B23:AA23=SAND);filter(Sheet1!B26:AA47;Sheet1!B48:AA48=SAND)}`

(The "=sand" is just "=true" in my language)

But I keep getting "An Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows"

I have no idea what is wrong. I've been trying stuff for over an hour, and each filter works as intended until I combine them in the {}.

Its in this sheet, in sheet2 cell C3: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z1Mbqcmnm8hu0ZN5HdSw_JI3bhby0lP7Z03NIg5vmKg/edit?usp=sharing

Anyone got an idea what is wrong?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Check by separate each function of  your formula. PS the sizes of the ranges on a FILTER function should have the same number of rows.

Comment: They both have 21 rows. I have tested them separately, they work fine in that case.

Comment: `Sheet1!B23:AA23` and `Sheet1!B48:AA48` have one row. Does the filter functions that use these ranges in the question are the same that you tested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are apparently trying to filter *columns* rather than *rows*, and using a locale where formula argument separators are semicolons rather than commas. Try this:

```
={
  filter(Sheet1!B1:AA22; Sheet1!B23:AA23 = true) 
  \ 
  filter(Sheet1!B26:AA47; Sheet1!B48:AA48 = true) 
}
```

See your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z1Mbqcmnm8hu0ZN5HdSw_JI3bhby0lP7Z03NIg5vmKg/edit#gid=731657150).

See the [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276) help page for more info on array delimiters.

Comment: Wow, thanks alot. No idea why that worked, even after reading the link since i have another sheet where i used ; rarther then the \ (which i have never used for this before).

But well, it works, and i know next time to try the \ - Thanks alot!